# Dreamhost php sql error 'could not find driver'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection

I have made numerous attempts, most returning the odd error of 'could not find driver' when using PDO. I've confirmed multiple times with customer support that my credentials are correct. I've gone over the code looking for bugs, and found none. I built some simple tests, two examples below, one returning the error of 'Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()', the other returning the aforementioned ''could not find driver'.

I've been reading and googling and have yet to find a solution which is able to provide a working connection. Hoping for guidance on how to proceed

test 1: produces 'driver not found' error

```
$host     = 'notmyHOST';
$db       = 'notmyDATABASE';
$password = 'notmyPASSWORD';
$user     = 'notmyUSERNAME';
    
    
$dsn = "mysqli:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=UTF8";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    if ($pdo) {echo "Connected to the $db database successfully!";}
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}



//test 2: produces 'driver not found' error
//This test is a straight line-for-line copy of the example connect code 
//provided by  Dreamhosts knowledge-base

$hostname = "mysql.example.com"; //hostname created when creating the database
$username = "yourusername";      //username specified for database
$password = "yourpassword";      //password specified for database access
$database = "databasename";      //database name specified at creation

$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   die("Connect failed: %s\n" + mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}



/*
  test 3: produces 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found in   
  /home/*****/*****/a___connectTEST4.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in  
  /home/*****/*****/a___connectTEST4.php on line 25' error
*/

$hostname = 'myHOST';
$database = 'myDATABASE';
$password = 'myPASSWORDS';
$username = 'myUSERNAME';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

To recap, I'mooking for advice/solution/how to proceed to resolve connection error in any of the tests provided. In all tests I checked all credentials multiple times, they are correct; Haven't found a solution which maps to my problem on Stack Overflow, but I've looked at similar issues without success.

[image: phpINFO SQL STUFF]
[image: phpINFO PDO STUFF]

Comment: _"the odd error of 'could not find driver' when using PDO"_ - Not that odd. You need to change `$dsn = "mysqli:` to `$dsn = "mysql:` (loose the `i`). The PDO driver is just called `mysql`.

Comment: I don't see why you would get _"Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()"_ though since that extension seem to be installed. If fixing your PDO (based on the above comment) doesn't work, you need to contact the hosting company again and explain these issues to them. Either way, these issues has nothing to do with your credentials.

Comment: @MagusEriksson   I did the following: $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=UTF8";

Comment: Still the same error - contacted my host, and their telling me it works on another server, and I'm having a heck of time gettn them to try it on mine as it does matter if it works over there, it's a 'does it work here' issue

Comment: Keep pestering them. As you say, it's completely irrelevant if it works on another server.